# Отправить сообщение в telegram из javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, telegram

Здравствуйте. Есть форма:

```
<div id="parent_popup">
    <div id="popup">
        <span id="close" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #666;"></i></span>
        <form role='form' id="call" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; margin: 48px 5px 0px 40px;"></i> {{ call_master.client }}
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px 0px 0px 42px;"></i>
                <div>{{ call_master.phone }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row center">
                <input type='submit' class="call-master-form" id='close-master-btn' value="Отправить заявку" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Обрабатывается и отсылается на сервер скриптом:

```
$(doc).on('submit', '#call', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: {
         'master-client': $('#id_master-client').val(),
         'master-phone': $('#id_master-phone').val(),
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
      },
      success: function() {
         $('#parent_popup').fadeOut('1000');
         doc.getElementById("call").reset();
      }
   });
});
```

Как можно отправить сообщение в скрипте на адрес http://pushmebot.ru/send?key=8dec1d50ac5ff3305e548&message=, с данными data, которые собираются из формы?
Спасибо за любой совет!

Answer (score 1):

может так?

```
$(doc).on('submit', '#call', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var msg = 'сообщение с формы, сюда ...';
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://pushmebot.ru/send',
      data: {
         'key' : '8dec1d50ac5ff3305e548',
         'message' : msg,

      },
      success: function() {
         $('#parent_popup').fadeOut('1000');
         doc.getElementById("call").reset();
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте в код скрытую картинку:

```
<img src="http://pushmebot.ru/send?key=8dec1d50ac5ff3305e548&message=test">
```